# Order a list of numbers from given list without built-in sort, copy if first number is greater than second number swap them

Tags: python, swap, pseudocode

I am tring to implement a function in a way that it does basically the same thing as `sorted(lst)` without using `sorted(lst)` or `var = lst.copy()` but I just can't figure it out how to work it that way and following exactly the way as it is written in the pseudo code.

Can someone please help me ?

My assesment is:

Below is the pseudocode of a sorting algorithm:

1. Starting from the beginning of a list, compare each element with its next neighbor.
2. If the element is larger than its next neighbour, change them places.
3. Go through the list to the end.
4. If there have been any mix-ups at step 2,go to step 1

my code right now:

```
def my_sort(lst):
    lst_sorted = []
    lst2 = lst.copy()
    compare = True
    while compare:
        compare = False
        num = lst2[0]
        if num not in lst_sorted:
            try:
                for x in lst2:
                    if x < num:
                        x, num = num, x
                        lst_sorted.append(num)
                    elif num < x:
                        compare = True
        else:
            compare = True
    return lst_sorted
```

the test code that my professor gave me:

```
def test_my_sort():
    lst_test = random.choices(range(-99, 100), k=6)
    lst_copy = lst_test.copy()
    lst_output = my_sort(lst_test)

    assert lst_copy == lst_test, "Error: my_sort (lst) changes the contents of list lst"
    assert lst_output == sorted(lst_test), \
        f"Error: my_sort ({lst_test}) returns {lst_output} instead of {sorted (lst_test)}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        test_my_sort()
        print("Your my_sort () function works fine!")
```

Comment: I presume you meant to start your code with `def my_sort(lst):`?

Comment: whoops I forgot to copy that ill edit that one sec

Comment: Can you use built-in function? You can use ```list(set(f))``` if you can use built-in function.

Comment: Is there a particular method that you are meant to use to make a new list so that it can be returned and you don't have to touch the given parameter?

Comment: my professor really didn't gave any more information than this. and I tried multiple ways but it always gives the ```assert lst_output == sorted(lst_test), \
            f"Error: my_sort ({lst_test}) returns {lst_output} instead of {sorted (lst_test)}"
``` back I think that he wants me to implement the code as the pseudocode. if number a is greater than number b swap them until it is not possible anymore like a linear search algorithm

Comment: So can you use: `lst_sorted = lst[:]` to make a copy?

Comment: @FaranAiki I don't know if that is allowed and he doesn't reply back to my questions if certain functions are allowed or not.

Comment: lets say I use ```lst_sorted = lst[:]```how can I implement the pseudocode that way ? @quamrana

Comment: Well, I think you have to make an honest attempt at implementing the pseudo-code.

Comment: my professor finally answered me and the function copy is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

### Straightforward solution

Following your intention of using a flag `compare` and the exact assesment rules, here is a step by step explanation :

```
def my_sort(lst):
    # We copy the list so that the changes are not made in the original variable.
    # We will modify lst2 from now.
    lst2 = lst.copy()
    compare = True
    while compare is True:
        # compare will remain False as long as there is no swapping
        compare=False
        # We walk the list index by index, excepted the last one
        # so we don't get an index error from the last "index+1"
        for i in range(len(lst2)-1):
            # If the first is greater than the second...
            if lst2[i]>lst2[i+1]:
                # We swap
                bump = lst2[i]
                lst2[i]=lst2[i+1]
                lst2[i+1]= bump
                # and set compare to True to ask for another iteration of the while loop
                compare=True
    return lst2
```

### Another way of swapping in Python

You can swap in one line:

```
for i in range(len(lst2)-1):
    if lst2[i]>lst2[i+1]:
       lst2[i], lst2[i+1] = lst2[i+1], lst2[i]
       compare=True
```

### Optimizing Bubble sort

This sorting algorithm is called `Bubble Sort`.

There is an optimization based on the observation that the largest value is always carried to the end slot in a single iteration. Therefore, in the worst case scenario, you can avoid `(n-1)**2` indexings by stopping one index earlier at each iteration.

Here is an adapted implementation:

```
def optimized_sort(lst):
    lst2 = lst.copy()
    compare = True
    #Creating a variable to store the iteration count
    n = 0
    while compare is True :
        compare=False
        # This time, we walk from index 0 to the last index minus the iteration count
        for i in range(len(lst2) - 1 - n):
            if lst2[i]>lst2[i+1]:
                lst2[i],lst2[i+1] = lst2[i+1], lst2[i]
                compare=True
        # We increment the iteration count
        n += 1
    return lst2
```

As you can see, the optimized one is indeed a bit more performing.
[image: Sorting comparision]

Of course, this algorithm remains a poorly performing one and mainly used for educational purpose.

Comment: for learning purposes would be performing this task without using the flag compare be faster ?

Comment: @KilimanJaro You need such a flag in the bubble sort if you want to detect that the list is sorted before any unnecessary other iteration. You can absolutely do it without flag if you ignore early detection and the 4th step of your assessment : instead of the while loop, put a for loop with n -1 iterations.

Comment: That obviously means it would be slower. One exception I can think of is if the list is initially sorted in the opposite order (largest to smallest). The flag method would iterate n times : n-1 times to sort, and one more time to check. The no-flag method would iterate n-1 times in total. Its benefit is very minimal in this case, but in almost any other case, the no-flag method would be slower. Also, for this very specific case, you could limit the while loop to n-1 iterations, in the optimized version, by adding a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning python, but this works for me:

```
def my_sort(lst):
    randHolder = []
    for ele in range(len(lst)):
        mini = min(lst)
        giveIndex = lst.index(mini)
        popped = lst.pop(giveIndex)
        randHolder.append(popped)
    lst = randHolder
    return lst
```

Comment: When I run your code it fails the professor's `test_my_sort()` function.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why that might be? If you add to my code '''import random''' and '''lst_test = random.choices(range(-99, 100), k=6)''' you will see that it correctly sorts the list every time.

Comment: Its because you do `lst.pop(giveIndex)`. That modifies the given parameter.